# how to solve memory leaks in AVAudioPlayer-iphonesdk

Tags: iphone

how to solve memory leaks in AVAudioPlayer-iphonesdk. here. i will give the my code.. memory leaks are in my code, how to solve it..

.h file

```
AVAudioPlayer *titlescreenaud;
```

.m file

```
titlescreenaud=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TitleScreen_BgmAudio" ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];//***Memory leaks on here......***   
titlescreenaud.numberOfLoops=-1;
[titlescreenaud play];
```

After finish the sound

```
       -(void)finish
        {
        [titlescreenaud stop];
        [titlescreenaud release];
        titlescreenaud=nil;
        }
```

how to release the avaudioplayer please help me.......

Answer (score 0):

```
titlescreenaud=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TitleScreen_BgmAudio" ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];//***Memory leaks on here......***
```

I assume Instruments is indicating that the memory leak is there.   What it means is that something allocated on that line has not been released.   The actual leak may be elsewhere and will most likely be because of a missing `release`.

Is your `finish` method really being called?  Do you `release` `titlescreenaud` in `dealloc`?

There isn't enough code here to be able to specifically pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are allocating AVAudioPlayer object in ViewDidLoad than you will not face the problem. But if you are calling methods repeatatively and in which you have allocated the object than it is always going to allocate the memory for the same object. You can check the retainCount before releasing the memory.

Comment: Do *not* check the `retainCount`.  The `retainCount` method is pretty much useless for debugging and should never be used in production code.

Comment: He is releasing the memory manually so i think he can use it. It is not good to use retaincount if you are using autorelease. Am i right bbum ?

Comment: Nope;  it is *never* a good idea to use `retainCount`.  The retain count of an object is an internal-to-the-frameworks implementation detail.  If it is an object from the frameworks or an object passed into the frameworks, the retain count could be just about anything and still be valid.